# why does JSON dump doesn't work in my code?

Tags: json, django, api

I'm trying to put python objects into a JSON file by getting the API from one of the sites but somehow when I run the code nothing has been put in the JSON file. API is working well, as well when I print out the code by json.load I get the output but I have no idea why does dump doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import json
import datetime
import re


def index(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    format = "{}-{}-{}".format(now.year, now.month, now.day)
    source = []
    author = []
    title = []
    date = []

    url = "http://newsapi.org/v2/everything"
    params = {
        'q': 'bitcoin',
        'from': format,
        'sortBy': 'publishedAt',
        'apiKey': '1186d3b0ccf24e6a91ab9816de603b90'
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, params=params)
    for news in response.json()['articles']:
        matching = re.match("\d+-\d+-\d+", news['publishedAt'])
        if format == matching.group():
            source.append(news['source'])
            author.append(news['author'])
            title.append(news['title'])
            date.append(news['publishedAt'])

    data = \
    {
        'source': source,
        'author': author,
        'title': title,
        'date': date
    }
    with open('data.json', "a+") as fp:
        x = json.dump(data, fp, indent=4)

    return render(request, 'news/news.html', {'response': response})
```

Comment: I think it is `json.dumps` not `json.dump`. try using `json.dumps`.

Comment: No, it is not, because dumps work with string so the input has to be a string such as: '{"a": 1}' but if I want to enter an object I have to use dump not dumps, however, I tried what you said but I get error

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: **key error: dumps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given**, this error often happens because the fp option that has to become string like I said but here I need to enter dictionary not a string

Comment: am I right or I miss something?

Comment: Ajay is correct here.  `json.dumps` does not take a string, but a data structure.

this example `json.dumps({"a": 1})` is creating a dict and passing that to `dumps`

Comment: the code has worked well now the error was no error but somehow Django create a new JSON file somewhere and didn't look at the file I created hence, the objects have written into it but I face another issue I'm working on it now, how can I separates data objects by comma I hope if anyone can tell me the way, I will appreciate it :)